# Tailwind peer class does not exist

Tags: webpack, tailwind-css, css-modules

I'm using tailwindcss version 3.0.7 and when I use the peer class in an @apply statement it throws an error saying 'The `peer` class does not exist.'

From what I read on the documentation, I think it might have to do with how I have jit set up. Any advice would be appreciated.

The css statement in a module.css file

```
.switchInput {
    @apply peer hidden
}
```

My postcss.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss')('./tailwind.config.js'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
  ],
};
```

My tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  purge: [
    './src/**/*.html',
    './dist/**/*.html',
    './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
  ],
  content: [
    './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
  ],
};
```

webpack.config.js

```
rules: {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [{ loader: 'style-loader' },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
            },
          },
          { loader: 'postcss-loader' }],
      },
```

Before you mention it, yes I shouldn't have to use apply statements, but I need to obfuscate all my class names in this project because I'm making an embeddable widget that needs to avoid name conflicts with any classes on the page. I also can't use a ShadowDOM because of the work its doing.

Comment: The `peer` and `group` utilities cannot be used with @apply https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/2848#issuecomment-734523233 this comment from Simon is about group, but same deal for peer.

Answer (score 4):

First, you should change your 'tailwind.config.js' file if you are using tailwind css v3.x. Remove 'mode: jit' because tailwind css v3.x uses Just-in-Time engine by default. Also you should remove 'purge' option and use 'content' instead; Right now you are using both, which is wrong. You can follow the instructions available in the [official upgrade guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide#migrating-to-the-jit-engine).

And as JHeth said in comments, it's better to not use 'peer' or 'group' utilities with @apply. Here is the [related link](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/2848#issuecomment-734523233) so you could understand why.

Answer (score 0):

It important to have class "peer" in html because everything you add trough @apply will be converted into css properties and class "peer" can't be converted into variable. For example:

```
 @apply flex flex-col;
```

will be converted into

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

As those classes are utilities.